# Проверка email-адреса

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Здравствуйте. Накопал в Интернете следующее регулярное выражение для проверки email-адреса:

> '#[a-z0-9_.-]+@([a-z0-9-]+.)+[a-z]{2,6}#ui'

Как его переделать так, чтобы он не пропускал email-адреса такого вида:

> http://1234[[[@mail](/users/15729/maila1501)](/users/15729/maila1501)](/users/15729/maila1501).ru
>
> www.1234[[[@mail](/users/15729/maila1501)](/users/15729/maila1501)](/users/15729/maila1501).ru
>
> https://1234[[[@mail](/users/15729/maila1501)](/users/15729/maila1501)](/users/15729/maila1501).ru
>
> http://www.1234[[[@mail](/users/15729/maila1501)](/users/15729/maila1501)](/users/15729/maila1501).ru

Comment: Суть вопроса. Нахождение в тексте email адресов и их замена в html теги. Нужна регулярка.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```

Comment: Прошу прощения. Я не совсем правильно задал вопрос. Вы вставили в регулярное выражение указание на Начало и Конец. Да. Это работает. Но только в том случае, если мы обрабатываем один лишь пришедший от клиента адрес email. Но мне надо бы, чтобы данное регулярное выражение работало по целому тексту. Прошу прощения. Надо было мне сразу правильно изъяснить суть проблемы.

Comment: @stashappy, так не сработает?

>> [a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}

Comment: Да. Именно так. Благодарю Вас.:-)

Comment: @ModaL, не хватает экрана перед точкой.  

    text@a$v(bb:cc

Пройдет проверку

Comment: @ReinRaus ♦, странно, но я ставил экран перед точкой, он почему-то убрался :/

Понял, это в цитате он сам тут убирается. Сделал через <pre>.

Comment: Вот это всё валидные адреса эл. почты, согласно [rfc3696](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3696):

    Abc\@def@example.com
    Fred\ Bloggs@example.com
    Joe.\\Blow@example.com
    "Abc@def"@example.com
    "Fred Bloggs"@example.com
    customer/department=shipping@example.com
    $A12345@example.com
    !def!xyz%abc@example.com
    _somename@example.com

Answer (score 1):

Вот регулярка, которая относительно полно проверяет на соответствие валидному адресу электронной почты. На практике неприменима, наверное : )

http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Answer (score 1):

А как же `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`???? О_О

Comment: > Суть вопроса. Нахождение в тексте email адресов и их замена в html теги. Нужна регулярка.